# Unsolved import:reactor in PyDev with twisted module

Tags: python, twisted, pydev

It seems like my Eclipse PyDev can not recognize some modules in Twisted. When I import reactor module Protocol module and Factory module:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
```

PyDev will notify me:

> Unsolved import:reactor
>
> Unsolved import:Protocol
>
> Unsolved import:Factory

but the code can work as expected (no errors).

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project, click properties, select PyDev - PYTHONPATH, and add the location of the `twisted` package to your PYTHONPATH.

This should be automatic for you if Twisted is already installed.  Please [file a bug against PyDev](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=577329&group_id=85796&func=browse) to indicate this.

Comment: I don't think it will work, reactor remained unresolved for me too, and I think that's because twisted uses some dynamic imports, so it can't discover them..

Answer (score 0):

This will happen for any python package folder... Eclipse never configures them automatically.
You should add your source folder/zip/jar or egg to your PyDev - PYTHONPATH as Glyph said.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was too much stuff in `PYTHONPATH`, not too little. When adding new interpreter for Python 2 in *Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter Python*, Eclipse automatically adds some subdirectories of `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. This broke the importing for me.

Remove subdirectories of `site-packages` from `PYTHONPATH` in the global settings as well as project settings. After that use *File > Restart*.